# Javascript onmouseover position mouse

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I have this script, which gives an image to the bot-right side of your cursor when you go over the image. I wan't to change the position, but since im not that "good" with **javascript**, I don't really know how to do that .

```
function followmouse(e){
var xcoord=offsetfrommouse[0]
var ycoord=offsetfrommouse[1]

var docwidth=document.all? truebody().scrollLeft+truebody().clientWidth : pageXOffset+window.innerWidth-15
var docheight=document.all? Math.min(truebody().scrollHeight, truebody().clientHeight) : Math.min(window.innerHeight)

if (typeof e != "undefined"){
    if (docwidth - e.pageX < defaultimagewidth + 2*offsetfrommouse[0]){
        xcoord = e.pageX - xcoord - defaultimagewidth; // Move to the left side of the cursor
    } else {
        xcoord += e.pageX;
    }
    if (docheight - e.pageY < defaultimageheight + 2*offsetfrommouse[1]){
        ycoord += e.pageY - Math.max(0,(2*offsetfrommouse[1] + defaultimageheight + e.pageY - docheight - truebody().scrollTop));
    } else {
        ycoord += e.pageY;
    }

} else if (typeof window.event != "undefined"){
    if (docwidth - event.clientX < defaultimagewidth + 2*offsetfrommouse[0]){
        xcoord = event.clientX + truebody().scrollLeft - xcoord - defaultimagewidth; // Move to the left side of the cursor
    } else {
        xcoord += truebody().scrollLeft+event.clientX
    }
    if (docheight - event.clientY < (defaultimageheight + 2*offsetfrommouse[1])){
        ycoord += event.clientY + truebody().scrollTop - Math.max(0,(2*offsetfrommouse[1] + defaultimageheight + event.clientY - docheight));
    } else {
        ycoord += truebody().scrollTop + event.clientY;
    }
}
gettrailobj().left=xcoord+"px"
gettrailobj().top=ycoord+"px"
```

}

I think i have the right code right here, if not, can anybody tell me what code i should paste then?

Answer (score 0):

This could help you for a start. I have not tried to optimize it.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/usalE)

My jQuery experience is limited, but I dont think proper syntax is the most important right now.